# Using web.config file for redirect

Tags: web-config

Using only the web.config file, I need to redirect from one domain to another, and I also need to redirect each individual page (there are 25 of them) in my website to its corresponding page under the new domain. And the renamed /index.htm page, which is the home page (same as the domain name alone) and which is /ghostwriter.htm needs to be redirected to its corresponding page, which will also be the new home page.

Thus: http://www.rainbowriting.com/ is the same page as http://www.rainbowriting.com/ghostwriter.htm (the index page).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure ASP.NET is handling .htm files (set this in IIS). Then configure `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="oldPage1.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newDomain.com/newPage1.htm" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="oldPage2.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newDomain.com/newPage2.htm" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <!-- etc. -->
</configuration>
```